# Convert pandas DataFrame column of comma separated strings to one-hot encoded

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (‘data’) made up of one column. Each row in the column is made of a string and each string is made up of comma separated categories. I wish to one hot encode this data.

For example,

```
data = {"mesh": ["A, B, C", "C,B", ""]}
```

From this I would like to get a dataframe consisting of:

```
index      A       B.     C
0          1       1      1
1          0       1      1
2          0       0      0
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Note that you're not dealing with OHEs.

#### `str.split` + `stack` + `get_dummies` + `sum`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

      mesh
0  A, B, C
1      C,B
2         

(df.mesh.str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True)
   .stack()
   .str.get_dummies()
   .sum(level=0))
df

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  0
```

---

#### `apply` + `value_counts`

```
(df.mesh.str.split(r'\s*,\s*', expand=True)
   .apply(pd.Series.value_counts, 1)
   .iloc[:, 1:]
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer'))

   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  0  0  0
```

---

#### `pd.crosstab`

```
x = df.mesh.str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True).stack()
pd.crosstab(x.index.get_level_values(0), x.values).iloc[:, 1:]
df

col_0  A  B  C
row_0         
0      1  1  1
1      0  1  1
2      0  0  0
```

Comment: ``\`` line continuation character and that indentation - mine eyes!

Comment: You are so fast at posting options really nice. Now this is  `piR-esque`

Comment: @JonClements fixed... :P

Answer (score 8):

Figured there is a simpler answer, or I felt this as more simple compared to multiple operations that we have to make.

1. Make sure the column has unique values separated be commas
2. Use get dummies in built parameter to specify the separator as comma. The default for this is pipe separated.

   ```
   data = {"mesh": ["A, B, C", "C,B", ""]}
   sof_df=pd.DataFrame(data)
   sof_df.mesh=sof_df.mesh.str.replace(' ','')
   sof_df.mesh.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
   ```

### OUTPUT:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   1
1   0   1   1
2   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If categories are controlled (you know how many and who they are), best answer is by @Tejeshar Gurram. But, what if you have lots of potencial categories and you are not interested in all of them. Say:

```
s = pd.Series(['A,B,C,', 'B,C,D', np.nan, 'X,W,Z'])
 
0    A,B,C,
1     B,C,D
2       NaN
3     X,W,Z
dtype: object
```

If you are only interested in categories B and C for the final df of dummies, I've found this workaround does the job:

```
cat_list = ['B', 'C']
list_of_lists = [ (s.str.contains(cat_, regex=False)==True).astype(bool).astype(int).to_list()  for cat_ in cat_list]
data = {k:v for k,v in zip(cat_list,list_of_lists)}
pd.DataFrame(data)

   B  C
0  1  0
1  0  1
2  0  0
3  0  0
```